Bingo card box changing sizes when selected
I'm trying to create a bingo card. I'd like for there to be a couple color options for people to use when selecting a box. However when choosing a color and selecting a box. This changes the box sizing and quickly offsets my whole bingo card.

What do I need to do to make sure that only the background color of the selected box changes and not the sizing of it?
I've tinkered with this code, but can't seem to stop the sizing from changing. Ideally only the background color changes matching whatever color the person playing chooses.
var selectedColor = "";
function generateCard() {
  var card = document.getElementById("bingoCard");
  card.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous card
  shuffleArray(words);
  var index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = card.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.textContent = words[index++];
      cell.onclick = markNumber;
      if (cell.classList.contains("marked") && selectedColor) {
        cell.classList.add(selectedColor);
      }
    }
  }
}
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
function markNumber() {
  if (!this.classList.contains("marked")) {
    this.classList.add("marked");
    if (selectedColor) {
      this.classList.add(selectedColor);
    }
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("marked");
    if (selectedColor) {
      this.classList.remove(selectedColor);
    }
  }
}
function changeColor(color) {
  selectedColor = color;
}


Can you share also the CSS rules declared for the 'selectedColor' target?

I don't have 'selectedColor' defined in the CSS rules, I missed that. How would the CSS need to be defined? My default td before a box is marked is this:
td,
color-button {
border: 2px solid;
color: black;
text-align: center;
font-size: large;
padding: 15px;
margin: 20px;
background-color: white;
}
I tried to set this as the 'selectedColor' target, but nothing changed when running it.

You are right that you don't have 'selectedColor' in your CSS rules. This is because it is a variable that could be any color that is selected. The cell.classList.add(selectedColor); expression makes me think that there could be a rule for whichever color is selected that may be causing the effect you have described.

Turns out the CSS for the overall table was clashing with the color selector CSS rules. It's now fixed.

Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review
